# alert iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, alert

When I test for bad data in a text field and try  to show an alert for missing or bad data the alert does not display. But I can get an alert to display in the viewDidLoad function

Here is the code

```
 import UIKit
 import CoreData

class SellViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate  {
 @IBOutlet weak var customer: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var bales: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Hey", message: "@ SellViewController viewDidLoad ", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Working!!", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

func checkDataInput(){

    print("checking data input customer.text  \(customer.text)")
    print("checking data input bales.text \(bales.text)")

    if (customer.text!.isEmpty) {
        customer.text = "REQUIRED"
        missingCustomer()
    }
if (bales.text!.isEmpty){
        availableAlert()
    }else{
        newQuantity = Int(bales.text!)!
     }

 func availableAlert() {
    print(" at availableAlert")

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Hey", message: "@ SellViewController func missingValues ", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Working!!", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)


func missingCustomer() {
    print(" at missingCustomer")
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Hey", message: "@ SellViewController func missingCustomer ", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Working!!", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

This displays alert at viewDidLoad but no alert when I have missing data. The print statements when I have missing data return as.

checking data input customer.text  Optional("")
checking data input bales.text Optional("")
 at missingCustomer
 at availableAlert
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

The fatal error happens because the user is not able to correct their response when they get the alert.

What am I doing wrong? Shouldn't the alert display immediately when my 
missingData functions are  triggered and the be able to correct their entries?

Comment: Why didn't you post the relevant code that isn't working since that is where your issue is?

Comment: Is the `missingData` function executed on the main thread? If not, use `DispatchQueue.main.async { /* display your alert here */ }` (or `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {  /* display your alert here */ }` in Swift 2.0)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a threading issue. Your data evaluation code is most likely executing on the main thread (you haven't posted it so cant say for sure) so when you try to do UI work, presenting an alert in this case, it will not execute. To fix this, try this code instead in your missingData function:

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Hey", message: "@ SellViewController viewDidLoad ", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Working!!", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion. Unfortunately I get the same results. I edited my post to include the relevant code, a view controller and several func. I must be doing something else wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Hey", message: "@ SellViewController viewDidLoad ", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Working!!", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

you can change the code to ->

```
 let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Hey", message: "@ SellViewController viewDidLoad ", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
 let alertButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Working!!", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default)
alert.addAction(alertButton)
present(alert, animated: true)
```